# Getting a specific value out of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I was trying to get an email address out of an array inside of another array.

```
[to] => Array ( [email@yourdomain.com] => James smith )
```

I want to get the email address extracted from this array.

When I get the `to` value from the first array and place it into a variable, when echoed it is an array.
From that variable, I would like to get the email address.

Could someone please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: Would you just show an entire array?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get a specific key from an array:

```
<?php
$a = ['to' => ['email@yourdomain.com' => 'James smith']];
echo array_keys($a['to'])[0];
```

will output `email@yourdomain.com`